# Streaming audio distorted when played in mobile safari in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-s3, safari, mp3

We are hosting mp3 files on AWS s3. We have built a web app (in React) that will play back the mp3s. However, it sometimes becomes distorted when played in Safari on iOS. The strange thing is that this does not happen all the time.

- Here is the original file (sometimes distorted): https://sayyit-prod-static-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/static/audio/Darrin+M.+McMahon.original.mp3
- Here is the file sounds when distorted: https://sayyit-prod-static-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/static/audio/WhatsApp+Video+2019-09-26+at+11.06.49+AM.mp4

Now, this distortion only happens when playing it through our app. When we provide a direct link to s3 (like I did above), it works. The distortion also happens when linking directly to s3 in our app.

Here are some ideas:

- The mp3 file is broken
- When going directly to the S3 link, it downloads entirely, which seems to allow the mp3 file to play perfectly

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample rate on this MP3 file is 16 kHz.  That's very low (not abnormal for voice), but also uncharacteristically low for a 128k MP3.  I suspect that there's a bug with the resampler (as the iPhone hardware is locked to 48 kHz anyway), or that you're hitting an edge case bug with the decoder.

I'd recommend that you stop using MP3 and solve a few things at once.  While MP3 is of acceptable quality, it's quality for a given bitrate isn't as good as alternatives.  These days, you should consider using Opus.  It's supported on iOS if muxed into a CAF file, and is extremely efficient.  You could drop the bitrate down to 48k for voice and still have excellent quality.  And, you'll bypass whatever resampling or decoding issue you're having now all in one go.

Comment: How compatible is Opus with browsers? The wikipedia page is scant on info. Mp3 was chosen mainly because it is compatible with all browsers.

Comment: @BarrySteyn Opus is very compatible.  https://caniuse.com/#feat=opus  If you need even better compatibility than that, I'd recommend using AAC.